# Is there any way to show vxml content into Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, vxml, voicexml

I am searching for VXML 2.1 help. I know vxml can be tested on tellme.com server. But I am searching, if there is any way to test vxml in Google Chrome. That is, can vxml content be shown on Google Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

To view the VXML generated in a Chrome browser you just need to enter the URL that the IVR or VXML browser uses to render the page.  Most IVR platforms provide logs or trace files that show what URL's the platform is using to fetch the VXML documents. Just paste the URL from the log into the address for Chrome and you should see the VXML that is generated.

If the page appears blank then right click on the page and select "View page source".  Most of the time the IVR platform just uses HTTP GET requests which work fine in the browser. But if it issues a POST, like when you record user input and save the audio file back to the application, then you will not be able to use Chrome.  Then you can use something like Fiddler to view the VXML as [described in this post](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2012/01/debugging-voicexml-applications-with.html).